# Find in raw sql by join table

Tags: sql

Given 3 tables. I need to build SQL query to find two actors who cast together the most and list the titles
of those movies. Sort alphabetically

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/r2Y9CpH8n7MHTeBaqEHe9S/0

Table film_actor

```
 Column     | Type                        | Modifiers
------------+-----------------------------+----------
actor_id    | smallint                    | not null
film_id     | smallint                    | not null
```

...
Table actor

```
 Column     | Type                        | Modifiers
------------+-----------------------------+----------
actor_id    | integer                     | not null 
first_name  | character varying(45)       | not null
last_name   | character varying(45)       | not null
```

...
Table film

```
 Column     | Type                        | Modifiers
------------+-----------------------------+----------
film_id     | integer                     | not null
title       | character varying(255)      | not null
```

...
The desired output:

```
first_actor | second_actor | title
------------+--------------+--------------------
John Doe    | Jane Doe     | The Best Movie Ever
```

...

Comment: Sample table data and expected result would help. [mcve]

Comment: @jarlh  Could you explain what I need to add? I provided the expected result at the bottom of the post

Comment: Yes, but matching sample data is missing. (A few rows per table is usually fine.)

Comment: @jarlh how can I add it?

Comment: @jarlh found a way https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/r2Y9CpH8n7MHTeBaqEHe9S/0

Answer (score 1):

Input data and expected results would be helpful. Also, please tag DB you're using. You can try below code and see if it works:

```
SELECT (a.first_name || ' ' || a.last_name) AS First_Actor,
       (b.first_name || ' ' || b.last_name) AS Second_Actor,
       c.title
FROM actor a
JOIN
  (SELECT a.actor_id AS first_actor,
          b.actor_id AS second_actor,
          a.film_id
   FROM film_actor a
   JOIN film_actor b ON a.film_id = b.film_id
   AND a.actor_id < b.actor_id) ab ON a.actor_id = ab.first_actor
JOIN actor b ON b.actor_id = ab.second_actor
JOIN film c ON c.film_id = ab.film_id
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!
It remains only to add the selection condition for only two actors who cast together the most.
And list only their films

Comment: mb you can help me with the last part too?